# JavaScript regex to verify correct pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check if a string is following a certain pattern, using js/regex:

The pattern is:
(8)lettersOrDigits-(4)lettersOrDigits-(4)lettersOrDigits-(4)lettersOrDigits-(12)lettersOrDigits (total 36 characters)

Example:
26cb3cca-6ce3-48d3-971d-950decffe749

Appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? https://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good place to start learning regular expressions. For JavaScript specifically: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Have you tried writing any regular expressions yourself yet? Please do that first

Comment: I tried something like this /([\d\w])+/g but it did not work.

Comment: @Ray be advised that by using `\w` you're also accounting for the `_` character (since it aliases `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`), which is most likely not something you'd want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can represent the set of letters or digits by using a character class:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

And you can specify exactly how many of those to match by using a quantifier:

```
{2} // change to whatever number you're looking for
```

So just put those together into a single regex, with anchors for the start and end of string:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$/
```

Because of the repeated groups of 4 in there, you could even further simplify it to:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-){3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$/
```

Then, just use the regex `.test` method to check if a string matches it or not. Here's an example using your test string and the above regex:

```js
const rgx = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-){3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$/;
console.log(rgx.test("26cb3cca-6ce3-48d3-971d-950decffe749"));
```

Comment: not only answers my question but clearly explains the concepts that were not really clear to me. Thanks a ton @CRice

Answer (score 2):

A bit long but...

```
^[a-z0-9]{8}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{12}$
```

If you want to account for uppercase than instead of `[a-z0-9]` use `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

```js
function validateCode ( code ) {
  return /^[a-z0-9]{8}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{12}$/.test(code);
}

console.log(
  validateCode("26cb3cca-6ce3-48d3-971d-950decffe749"), // true
  validateCode("26cb3ca-6ce3-48d3-97d-950decf9")        // false
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use helper site to understand the regular expressions.

https://www.regextester.com/?fam=103292

Following satisfies the pattern:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$
```

Please refer cheatsheets at http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html